# how to list all matches in easymotion vim

Tags: vim

I want the easy motion list all the matches in a window, like using the combination of vimgrep and quickfix. 
When searching a string in easymotion, it only shows the matches in current screen and I can jump to every position in current screen. How can I use the easy motion list all matches of the entire file, not the matches in current screen, into a sub window and can jump the matches position in file?
Thanks

Comment: This is a very strange question. Are you sure you are actually using Easymotion?

Comment: There may be some misleading in my presentation for engilsh is not my native language. I re-edit my question. I think is there some tools like micro world or VS that can list all matches in a window. I also go over the doc of easymotion, but cann't find this feature (perhaps reason by my poor english).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easymotion may be useful for *navigation* but it's completely useless for *search*.

You already know `:help :grep` and `:help :vimgrep`:

```
:grep foo %
:vim foo %
```

`:grep` is generally the fastest of the two but it only searches in actual files whereas `:vimgrep` also searches in buffers, as long as they correspond to an actual file.

You can also combine `:help :g` and `:help :#`:

```
:g/foo/#
```

Or make use of `:help include-search`:

```
:ilist foo
```